# Inserting emoji - smartphones in MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: mysql, php

Well with the the asks from is quite high explanatory will only strengthen the question.

APP have a chat system which be late the HTML , send it to PHP with ajax , but the usurer try to insert some emoji (emotion) of your device in the database he gets: "???" as a message.

How can I change this so that receive some kind of code for each emotion and the site list according to the value of it?

[image]

Comment: Little enough to do with databases, but I'll bite - take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) for codes. You'll have to do your processing using PHP or similar though.

Comment: Please don't close this. It is database-related in this instance. I have posted a plausible answer.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA How the heck did you read it? I can only read about one sentence here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have this sinking feeling inside that you have a character set problem if you are using InnoDB.

When you connect to MySQL, run this query

```
select
    A.variable_name,
    A.variable_value global_value,
    B.variable_value session_value
from
(
    select * from information_schema.global_variables
    where variable_name like 'collation%'
) A
inner join
(
    select * from information_schema.session_variables
    where variable_name like 'collation%'
) B
using (variable_name);
```

My guess is you are going to see a difference, especially with [**collation_connection**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection).

My suggestion: Make the [**collation_connection**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection) for the session the same as the global value.

```
select A.variable_value,B.variable_value,C.variable_value
into @coll_conn,@coll_db,@coll_srvr from
(
    select * from information_schema.global_variables
    where variable_name like 'collation_connection'
) A,
(
    select * from information_schema.global_variables
    where variable_name like 'collation_database'
) B,
(
    select * from information_schema.global_variables
    where variable_name like 'collation_server'
) C;
set session collation_connection = @coll_conn;
set session collation_database = @coll_db;
set session collation_server = @coll_srvr;
```

You can then verify the change within your session by running the first query again.

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

NOTE: I am only suggesting this because a Developer approached me with this situation last week and I ran the same queries, [showing him that the database was not at fault](https://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/e21cb478-f53b-4028-9d31-b69010e07257-medium.png). The app was changing the collation in the session after authenticating.

[image: Not The Database]

Answer (score 6):

This is a character set issue, not just an emoji issue.

Use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` throughout.

- In the client
- In the connection (`mysqli_set_charset` or PDO equivalent)
- In the table (or column) definitions
- `<meta ... utf-8>` in the html header.

Comment: Yup.  To clarify in more detail: emojis require utf8mb4 rather than just utf8.